# Page number appears twice in the page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I don't know why I am getting two page numbers on the same page, one in the center and one on the right:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\voffset=-1in

%setting the header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{Mohammad Noorani Bakerally}
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{Pattern-Based Development}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
The aim of the application is to create a Sushi plate and show its details.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Why does the one in the center still appear?

Comment: If the given answer help you solve the problem, please kindly accept it by clicking the check mark button below its score. Clicking the check mark button makes it green and increase your acceptance. The higher acceptance you have, the higher chance people help your other questions. :-)

Comment: done, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to remove the default center foot:

Add

```
\cfoot{}
```

Comment: It's usually advised to clear the header/footer entirely. Hence the use of `\fancyhf{}`.